# Proper way to create geometry base view in code

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

What is the proper method in the view controller lifecycle to create a geometry base view?
Like create a label in the middle of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method. This method called to notify the view controller that its view has just laid out its subviews.
Inside this method you can access calculated `view.frame` property.

Comment: But if you create view in that method every time your geometry change the view create again

Comment: You can create view in `viewDidLoad` and update its position in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: guess it is the best way. Thanks~